# Natural Language Processing for Android

Tags: android, nlp

I was interested in what opensource NLP APIs people on stackoverflow have used and liked for working on Android? Have you found performance issues related to doing NLP on Android Devices?

Comment: Hey @esse, I did not downvote your question, but I noticed someone did. Please read [ask] to learn why they might have downvoted you. Generally before asking one-liner questions you want to back the question up with some research, code examples, errors, etc... This question could almost be directly typed into google for an answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is an old question that I should probably delete. I hope I have learned to ask a little be better questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no. However, there is a lot of NLP code in Java, so it could certainly be ported over, especially if you didn't want to do any training and instead just use a statistical model to classify stuff.

A better question would be what exactly are you trying to do, and how much NLP/ML power do you need?